# Filtering multiple tags in Ansible dynamic inventory

Tags: ansible

I think I've seen an answer to this *somewhere*, but I can't seem to find it now.  I'm creating a dynamic `development` inventory file for my EC2 instances. I'd like to group all instances tagged with `Stack=Development`. Moreover, I'd like to specifically identify the development API servers. Those would not only have the `Stack=Development` tag, but also the `API=Yes` tag.

My basic setup uses inventory folders:

```
<root>/development
  ├── base
  ├── ec2.ini
  └── ec2.py
```

In my `base` file, I'd like to have something like this:

```
[servers]
tag_Stack_Development

[apiservers]
tag_Stack_Development && tag_API_Yes
```

Then I'd be able to run this to ping all of my development api servers:

```
ansible -i development -u myuser apiservers -m ping
```

Can something like that be done? I know the syntax isn't right, but hopefully the intent is reasonably clear? I can't imagine I'm the only one who's ever needed to filter on multiple tags, but I haven't been able to find anything that gets me where I'm trying to go.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not the answer I had in my head, but sometimes what's in my head just gets in the way. Since each inventory directory has its own `ec2.ini`, I just filter the stack there and then group within that filter.

```
# <root>/development/ec2.ini
...
instance_filters = tag:Stack=Development

# <root>/development/base
[tag_Role_webserver]
[tag_API_Yes]

[webservers:children]
tag_Role_webserver

[apiservers:children]
tag_API_Yes
```

Answer (score 6):

The answer provided by xiong-chiamiov does actually work. I've just been using it in my ansible deployment.

So I have a playbook using the dynamic inventory script. with this piece of code:

```
    ---
    - name: AWS Deploy
      hosts: tag_Environment_dev:&tag_Project_integration
      gather_facts: true
```

And the process does filter the hosts by both of those tags.

*EDIT*

Actually expanding on this, you can also use variables to make the host group specification dynamic. like this:

```
    ---
    - name: AWS Deploy
      hosts: "tag_Environment_{{env}}:&tag_Project_{{tag_project}}"
      sudo: true
      gather_facts: true
```

I use the {{env}} and {{tag_project}} vars from variable files and arguments given to ansible at runtime. It successfully changes the hosts the playbook runs against.

Comment: Also important to update aws_ec2.yml with a keyed_groups entry for each tag being used

Answer (score 2):

The Ansible documentation has [a section on patterns](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_patterns.html).  Rather than creating a new section, you can do a tag intersection when you specify the hosts:

```
[$] ansible -i development -u myuser tag_Stack_Development:&tag_API_Yes
```

This also works within playbooks.

Comment: @kev I don't have an ec2 account available to me at the moment, but I think that I've done this before.  What is leading you to believe it doesn't work?

Comment: And what did it do?  Do the two tags work when you specify them individually?

Comment: for me neither. Individual ones work, but not combined. I guess you'd have modified the ec2.py plugin for this?