# AWS Ansible Dynamic Inventory targeting hosts or making dynamic groups using multiple tags

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-inventory

I'll thank you in advance for reading, and extra thanks to anyone who can help!!

So firstly, I've read the two related posts below, but neither answer my question, or certainly not in a way I could make work:

[Filtering multiple tags in Ansible dynamic inventory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36748711/filtering-multiple-tags-in-ansible-dynamic-inventory)

[Ansible Multi Group Dynamic Inventory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67483443/ansible-multi-group-dynamic-inventory)

So I have around 100 AWS instances, with various tags as you'd expect.  I want to be able to use the aws_ec2 plugin to be able to create groups of hosts which I can then reference in the playbooks.

I was hoping to define the groups in the aws_ec2.yml file, but so far I've had no luck.

```
  plugin: aws_ec2
  regions:
    - eu-xxxx-x
  filters:
    instance-state-name: running
groups:
keyed_groups:
  # Creates a group for each value of the Application tag
  - key: tags
    prefix: tag
  # Creates a group for each value of the Platform tag
  - key: platform
    prefix: platform
hostnames:
  - tag:Name
compose:
  ansible_host: private_ip_address
```

> **Sample Data:**

Obviously this is just an example using generic data, but you get the idea.  I want to be able to join both network and role to create a group.
*(Please ignore the formatting, it's just so you can see the tag names and possible values)*

```
tags:
  name: network
  values:
    net1
    net2

  name: role
  values:
    client
    server
```

The following hosts have the following tags (again ignore the formatting):

```
svr-host1:
  network: net1
  role: server
svr-host2:
  network: net1
  role: server
cli-host1:
  network: net1
  role: client
cli-host2:
  network: net1
  role: client
cli-host3:
  network: net1
  role: client

svr-host3:
  network: net2
  role: server
svr-host4:
  network: net2
  role: server
cli-host4:
  network: net2
  role: client
cli-host5:
  network: net2
  role: client
cli-host6:
  network: net2
  role: client
```

> **Output from ansible-inventory command**

I get the expected output of all the hosts for each value of the network tag and all the hosts for each value of the role tag.

```
"tag_network_net1": {
    "hosts": [
        "svr-host1", 
        "svr-host2", 
        "cli-host1", 
        "cli-host2", 
        "cli-host3"
        ]
    }, 
"tag_network_net2": {
    "hosts": [
        "svr-host3", 
        "svr-host4", 
        "cli-host4", 
        "cli-host5", 
        "cli-host6"
        ]
    },
"tag_role_server": {
    "hosts": [
        "svr-host1", 
        "svr-host2", 
        "svr-host3", 
        "svr-host4", 
        ]
    }, 
"tag_role_client": {
    "hosts": [
        "cli-host1", 
        "cli-host2", 
        "cli-host3"
        "cli-host4", 
        "cli-host5", 
        "cli-host6"
        ]
    }
```

> **Desired Outcome:**

I want to be able to group the hosts using tags, then be able to use those groups in a playbook as follows:

```
# Groups and the associated hosts
net1_servers:
  svr-host1:
  svr-host2:
net2_servers:
  svr-host3:
  svr-host4:
net1_clients:
  cli-host1:
  cli-host2:
  cli-host3:
net1_clients:
  cli-host4:
  cli-host5:
  cli-host6:
```

Playbook:

```
- hosts: net1_servers,net1_clients
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
  - name: blah blah
....
```

Comment: Ok, "so far I've had no luck." because ... _what_ happens instead? When you run `ansible-inventory -i ./whatever.aws_ec2.yml --list`, what do you get versus what you wish you got?

Comment: Thanks for looking, have updated post with output of ansible-inventory cmd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems their `keyed_groups:` behavior is the same as their [jinja2 `groups:` tests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62124186/225016) -- they use `key:` as an *accessor* against the `ec2 describe-instances` data (after it's been `camel_case_to_snake_case`, just like how one would see from [`amazon.aws.ec2_instance_info:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/5/collections/amazon/aws/ec2_instance_info_module.html#return-values)) and if it returns something then they use that returned value in combination with `prefix:` to assign that host to one or more dynamic groups

For clarity, `key:` is a fully blown jinja2 expression, so you could also glue together the items to make a composite, which may have been what you were asking for to begin with

```yaml
# the contents of "my_inv.aws_ec2.yml"
plugin: amazon.aws.aws_ec2
region: us-east-1
hostnames:
- tag:Name
keyed_groups:
- # language=python
  key: tags.get('net', 'NN') + "_" + tags.get('role', 'RR')
  prefix: net_role
- # language=python
  key: tags.get('network', 'UNKNOWN_NET')
  prefix: net
- key: tags.get('role', 'UNKNOWN_ROLE')
  prefix: role
```

Thus yielding:

```json
    "all": {
        "children": [
            "aws_ec2",
            "net_role_net1_client",
            "net_role_net1_server",
            "net_net1",
            "net_net2",
            "role_client",
            "role_server",
            "ungrouped"
        ]
    },
    "net_net1": {
        "hosts": [
            "client-net1-1",
            "client-net1-2",
            "client-net1-3",
            "client-net1-4",
            "server-net1-1",
            "server-net1-2",
            "server-net1-3",
            "server-net1-4"
        ]
    },
    "net_net2": {
        "hosts": [
            "client-net2-1",
            "client-net2-2",
            "client-net2-3",
            "client-net2-4",
            "server-net2-1",
            "server-net2-2",
...
    "role_client": {
        "hosts": [
            "client-net1-1",
            "client-net1-2",
            "client-net1-3",
            "client-net1-4",
            "client-net2-1",
            "client-net2-2",
...
    "role_server": {
        "hosts": [
            "server-net1-1",
            "server-net1-2",
...
```

Then, you can either target that unified group, or take advantage of their ["intersection" `hosts:` syntax](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/5/user_guide/intro_patterns.html#common-patterns)

```yaml
- hosts: net_role_net1_client
  ...

# or:
- hosts: 'role_client,&net_net1'
  # ...

# or, if you prefer, it also honors the jinja2 mustaches:

- hosts: 'role_{{ the_role }},&net_{{ the_net }}'
  ...
# ansible-playbook -e the_role=server -e the_net=net1 ...
```

```
PLAY [net_net1,&role_client] ***************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [client-net1-2] => {
    "inventory_hostname": "client-net1-2"
}
ok: [client-net1-4] => {
    "inventory_hostname": "client-net1-4"
}
ok: [client-net1-3] => {
    "inventory_hostname": "client-net1-3"
}
ok: [client-net1-1] => {
    "inventory_hostname": "client-net1-1"
}
```

---

This is likely WAAAAY beyond what anyone else cares about, but it took so much dumbness that I thought I'd write it down to <s>save someone the trouble</s> remind myself for the next time this line of questioning comes up :-D

Here's how I was able to test that:

```sh
# be sure not to do this in your actual $HOME, or you'll bork your awscli
cd $(mktemp -d /tmp/XXXXXX)

mkdir -p .aws/models
# nuke the other partitions, otherwise "aws_ec2" tries to contact them
jq '{
  partitions: [.partitions[] | select(.partition == "aws")],
  version
}' $(brew --prefix ansible)/libexec/lib/python*/site-packages/botocore/data/endpoints.json \
  > .aws/models/endpoints.json
# a pleasing side-effect of running that through jq is that it now has uniform syntax
# I'm running moto on 4566, YMMV
sed -i.bak -e 's/"https"/"http"/; s/"hostname": "[^"]*"/"hostname": "127.0.0.1:4566"/' \
  .aws/models/endpoints.json

$(brew --prefix)/moto/bin/moto_server -p 4566 &

export AWS_REGION=us-east-1
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=whatever
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=sekrit

# populate the hosts
for n in net1 net2; do
  for r in client server; do
    for x in 1 2 3 4; do
      HOME=$PWD aws ec2 run-instances --cli-input-json '{
  "ImageId": "ami-1234",
  "TagSpecifications": [
    {
      "ResourceType": "instance",
      "Tags": [
        {
          "Key": "Name",
          "Value": "'${r}-${n}-${x}'"
        },
        {
          "Key": "network",
          "Value": "'$n'"
        },
        {
          "Key": "role",
          "Value": "'$r'"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}'
    done
  done
done

# now we can check that aws_ec2.yml matches our expectations
ansible-inventory -i ./my_inv.aws_ec2.yml --list
```

Comment: mdaniel, wow... and huge thank you for taking the time and effort to both look into the issue, and provide a very clear explanation and example .....   I'm going to test this out in a couple of days time as I've a few days off.. but as soon as I tried it... there will either be much praise and thanks... or more questions.!   Either way, thank you very much.